# Jsonifying bits from MySQLdb in Python

Tags: python, mysql-python

I'm reading a MySQL record using `MySQLdb` in Python. One of the columns is a bit. 
It's shows up as either `\\u0000` or `\\u0001` on the Python console when I use `json.dumps` to covert it to JSON (it's shows as `\x00` before conversion) and send it to the browser, the browser shows nothing. I'm assuming it's because it doesn't know the character for the Unicode.

Is there a way for me to get Javascript `True` or `False` for these values by manipulation at either the client or the server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

manipulating it a server side is as simple as:

```
import json

def convert_to_bool(bstring):
    return True if bstring == b'\x00' else False
```

example usage:

```
your_byte_string = b'\x00'
# you can write also
# your_byte_string = u'\u0000'

print(json.dumps(convert_to_bool(your_byte_string))) 

# >>> true

your_byte_string = b'\x01'
# you can write also
# your_byte_string = u'\u0001'

print(json.dumps(convert_to_bool(your_byte_string)))

# >>> false
```

then, eventually you may desire to add some code to -say- show an image if this field is true. This can be done both at server side or at client side.

**SERVER SIDE**

if you do not plan to use the boolean variable in your javascript code, you can send directly the expected HTML:

```
if convert_to_bool(your_byte_string):
    # here I'm just printing it but you should use the dumped string as a json response
    print(json.dumps('The field is <b>true</b>!'))
else:
    print(json.dumps('Unfortunately the field is <b>false</b>.'))
```

**CLIENT SIDE**

If you are using json I suppose you know how to do that, it's basic javascript, however for the sake of completeness here is the code:

```
// javascript code
// yourdata is the field value, retrieved by the ajax call 

if (yourdata) {
    alert('The field is true!');    
} else {
    alert('The field is false!');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer

Comment: you're welcome :) I suppose you just needed the first 4 lines of my answer but I preferred to articulate them in order to provide reference for future readers

Comment: Well... I'm still looking for a way to do this efficiently with tuples... I get the columns as tuples and ideally the JSON would have key-value pairs with column-name/values and the `\x00` bit fixed during the parsing. Will probably have to write a custom parser.